# wxpython on Mac - button style

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, cocoa, wxpython

I am using wxPython3.0-osx-cocoa-py2.7 on Mac 10.11.5 with python 2.7.11. Looking at the documentation, for wxmac it show the buttons looking like this:

[image]

But my buttons look like this:

[image]

I am using this code:

```
closeBtn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Close")
closeBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)
```

How can I get mey buttons to look like the wxmac example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image in the documentation was from a screenshot in an older version of OSX.  Since wxPython uses the native widgets, then they always look the same as the widgets in the current version of the OS (because they are the same widget).